# How can I move a module block's title to display within the block's template?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

When I give my module block a title it displays above my module block.
How can I move this to display within my blocks template and not display above the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the [block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) template:

create a template called block--block-name.tpl.php OR override all block templates by using block.tpl.php and move the code the prints the title into the content div:

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($block->subject): ?>
       <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
      <?php endif;?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use this block override template in the module though?
So the module is self contained.

Comment: If you are using the blocks hook then you can add your template to the theme or module directory.

Comment: I have a block template that I am adding via hook_theme_registry_alter() but still the title is before the block.
Could you provide an example?